# How to insert payments logo opencart footer

Tags: icons, opencart, e-commerce, opencart-3, logos

How can I insert payments logos in the footer for opencart 3.X?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can Edit Footer Template file : catalog\view\theme\default\template\common\footer.twig

Replace

```
<p>{{ powered }}</p>
```

to

```
<p>{{ powered }}<img src="/image/yourimage path/yourimagename.png"
width="500" height="50" class="img-responsive" alt="Payment"
style="float:right"></p>
```

I think it will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Edit footer template file catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/footer.tpl

Change

```
<p><?php echo $powered; ?></p>
```

to

```
<p><?php echo $powered; ?></font><img src="/image/yourimage path/yourimagename.png" width="480" height="40" class="img-responsive" alt="payment methods" style="float:right"></p>
```

May need to vary width\height as required

Comment: Why are you using <font color="#FFF"> tags to make the powered text white? Are you from 1997?

Comment: I think it is because is still working...  https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp
And seems  it is not prohibited.. till now.

Comment: Why not just remove that text if you don't want it shown?

Answer (score 0):

In 3.x if you have BurnEngine installed you can change it via BurnEngine -> Theme Settings -> Payment images.

[image]